# close button on right of text-centered breadcrum with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am trying to create a modal with a centered breadcrum on top and a close button on the very right, on the same line of the breadcrum.

I am using Bootstrap 3

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal container">
  <div class="modal-content col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="breadcrumb-container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb modal-breadcrum">
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-one">Abonnement</li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-two">Inscription</li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-three">Paiement</li>
        </ol>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
          <span id="close-btn" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this, The breadcrum is at its rights place, centered on top of the modal. 
But the close button is also centered, wrapped under the breadcrum.

How can I achieve this ?

What I actually want is:

```
<!-- some space here --> centered Breadcrum <!-- some space here --> X
```

Comment: Used `float:right` for button to place on right side..

Comment: Hi @MinalChauhan, thank you for your help ! the `close` bootstrap class already has the `float:right` property. However, it still wraps the button under the breadcrum.

Comment: <ol class="breadcrumb modal-breadcrum"> I think there is a b missing at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after some research, I found a good solution:

simply put the button out of the row, actually before the breadcrum row:

```
<div class="modal container">
  <div class="modal-content col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span id="close-btn" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="breadcrumb-container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb modal-breadcrum">
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-one">Abonnement</li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-two">Inscription</li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-step step-three">Paiement</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that, as @Minal Chauhan mentionned, the button must have the `float: right` property, and he bootstrap `close` class gives it to the button.